# Error when connecting to a SQL database: Cannot open database "Students.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-express

I am really frustrated, this is very simple but didn't work with me. I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server which I don't need username and password when running SSMS. My server name is `HP\SQLEXPRESS` and I'm using the following connection string:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Students.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

and I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot open database "Students.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'HP\Aymen'.

And when I specify the full address of my database as follows:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\Students.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

it also gives me the same error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Initial Catalog=Students.mdf, delete mdf

Comment: can you connect via SSMS with windows auth? also try HP\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: try Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\Students;Integrated Security=false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved. It seems that the problem is because I already have made a connection to the database using Entity Framework model. When I removed it and run the application again everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

when you're connecting from the SSMS, you have admin privileges.
i think this is not the case of the user that run your program.

however, i would suggest you to create a specific user using [create login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx)
then, simply just add your parameters to
[sql server connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: verify the login account you created, try to login from the SSMS using the new account

Answer (score 0):

Try using sa login to access the database

```
User ID=sa;
Password="your password without quotes";
```

and

```
data source=.
```

in your connection string

### UPDATED CONNECTION STRING

**FOR WINDOWS Auth.**

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Students;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

**FOR SQL AUTH.**

```
string connectionString="Data Source=.;User ID=sa;
Password=; Initial Catalog=Students; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient";
```

Comment: which password? I don't have any.

Comment: password for user 'sa' which you had entered during installation of SSMS

Comment: but I didn't enter any password during the installation.

Comment: try blank password field

Comment: I tried and got the following error: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

try this

I think Your are using Windows Authentication

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=Students;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have permissions problem for that user.

have you tried login with other user (admin user) to that db?

1. use your admin user to login to ssms.
2. under security, change the server Roles and user mapping to that specific user you want, and try to login again. do forget to give that user permission to "master".

Answer (score 0):

seems authentication issue here. you should specify the user id too in the connection string.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Students;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=PCName\WindowsUser;";
```

If still doesn't work then try this also.

```
string connectionString = "Server=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Students;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: I am still having problem with both statements. The error message is:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot open database "Students" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'HP\Aymen'.

Comment: if the database is created by administrator and the windows user `HP\Aymen` is not a admin then u cannot connect database using windows authentication. Either you have to login with `Admin` user or try to connect sql server with `Sql Authentication`. But, I don't think that you have installed your sql server with mixed mode. So, it can be run in both kind of authentication (Windows and SQL). So, check the user name when u connect the database from SSMS and use that username in the connection string.

Comment: Thanx Nimesh, anyway, the problem solved and the solution up.